# How can I trigger a Apps Scripts function in Google Sheets when a row is updated through the API (Zapier)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, zapier

i cant get my function to trigger when the sheet is edited via Api - it only works when the sheet is updated manually.

for context- sheet2 collects the api information using zapier from stripe and sheet1 is updated from this

```
function incrementNumber(e) {
    var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet2");
    var data1 = sheet1.getDataRange().getValues();
    var columnA = 1;
    var editedRow = e.range.getRow();
    var editedCol = e.range.getColumn();
    var updatedValue = sheet2.getRange(editedRow, columnA).getValue();
    var updatedDate = sheet2.getRange(editedRow, columnA+1).getValue();
    var matchFound = false;
    var newRow;
    if (editedCol == columnA) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data1.length; i++) {
            if (data1[i][columnA-1] == updatedValue) {
                matchFound = true;
                var nextColumn = sheet1.getRange(i+1, columnA+1).getValue() || 0;
                sheet1.getRange(i+1, columnA+1).setValue(nextColumn+1);
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!matchFound) {
            newRow = data1.length + 1;
            sheet1.getRange(newRow, columnA).setValue(updatedValue);
            if (updatedDate >= new Date("2023-01-01T00:00:00.000Z") && updatedDate <= new Date("2023-01-04T17:30:00.000Z")) {
                sheet1.getRange(newRow, columnA+1).setValue(1);
            } else if (updatedDate > new Date("2023-01-04T17:30:01.000Z") && updatedDate <= new Date("2023-01-11T17:30:00.000Z")) {
                sheet1.getRange(newRow, columnA+1).setValue(2);
            } else if (updatedDate > new Date("2023-01-11T17:30:01.000Z") && updatedDate <= new Date("2023-01-18T17:30:00.000Z")) {
                sheet1.getRange(newRow, columnA+1).setValue(3); 
            } else if (updatedDate > new Date("2023-01-18T17:30:01.000Z") && updatedDate <= new Date("2023-01-25T17:30:00.000Z")) {
            } 
        }
    }
}

function onEdit(e) {
    var editedSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
    if(editedSheet.getName() === "Sheet2") {
        incrementNumber(e);
    }
}
```

i tried time intervals but i couldnt get it to work

Comment: That's correct there is no trigger that responds to edits by formulas or other scripts. You are out of luck.

Comment: As @Cooper says, you're out of luck, but you can work around it with a trigger that keeps track of the sheet state. You'll have a few minutes delay, but it will get the job done. Alternatively, you can have the Zapier trigger a `doGet` or `doPost` function in a web app, and then it can do what you need. Just be creative :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to use [installable triggers][1] in your Google Sheet (scripts)
   and try to use "On change" instead of "On edit" event trigger (this will allow apps scripts to catch new row inserting).
2. Don't forget to set necessary permissions into your manifest:

- Go to "Project settings"
- Set tick on "Show "appsscript.json" manifest file in editor" option
- Go to code editor
- Go to "appsscript.json"
- Set:

````
"oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.currentonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"
]```

![Trigger "On change" example][2]


  [1]: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxNQN.png
````

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I succeeded in having a trigger execute an app script function after a row was added by API (make.com). I set the trigger to OnChange and in the sheet where the row is added by API, I have an Arrayformula that evaluates all rows in a column (and sets a value in the new row). Hope it helps.